# Webview source code in blackberry10

Tags: blackberry-10

Hi friends I am developing an application in Blackbery10 to parse the xml data in an html page. That the html is loaded in a webview and the html source contains some xml tags. Please help me to get the html source code of web view in blackberry10.

Answer (score 2):

On the Webview you can use a function [evaluateJavaScript (const QString &script, bb::cascades::JavaScriptWorld::Typeworld world)](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__cascades__webview.html#evaluatejavascript) to execute a javascript function to get the text or xml you need. You should be able to evaluate the following expression:

```
return document.documentElement.innerHTML;
```

You can then retrieve the evaluated expression from the signal [javaScriptResult](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__cascades__webview.html#javascriptresult)

Comment: please suggest me some samples that describe this

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the HTML of a WebView that was loaded from network

If you want an application highly based on HTML, you can have a look at WebWorks. If you still require the native framework, you have to request the content yourself, parse it, and then inject it into the webview.

Comment: But how to request the contents

Comment: i am looking for the  method available in blackbery 6 that is"public void documentLoaded(BrowserField browserField,
    Document document)"

Comment: You can request the content with "setUrl (const QUrl &url)", but you will not have such a signal. You have the signal void navigationRequested, but without the data. You cannot access by anyway the data loaded from the web